# Execute this.function in setInterval

Tags: javascript

I want to call `this.cycle` every `this.delay` ms when I call `this.start`.
Of course, this is not working :

```js
function Timer(delay, repetitions){
  this.delay = delay;
  this.maxrep = repetitions;
  this.rep = 0;

  this.start = function(){
    this.interval = setInterval(function(){
      this.cycle();
    },this.delay);
  }

  this.cycle = function(){
    this.rep++;
    console.log(this.rep);
    if(this.rep >= this.max){
      clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue I can see is that `this` inside the timer function is not the this you think it is.

So either

```
var me = this
this.start = function(){
  this.interval = setInterval(function(){
    me.cycle();
  },this.delay);
}
```

or just use an arrow function

```
this.start = function(){
  this.interval = setInterval(() => this.cycle(), this.delay);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not used to arrow functions, that's why.